# replace code block in terraform file

Tags: bash, jenkins, sed, aws-lambda, terraform

I am running a build on my Jenkins server and I am looking to dynamically populate the git_commit field with the commit number from the current build. The file has multiple functions in it and I want to use sed to match core-lambda-function1 name of the module and update the git_commit field with the commit number from the current build. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
module "core-lambda-function1" {
  source  = "./lambda"
  name    = "core-lambda-function"
  runtime = "nodejs6.10"
  role    = "${aws_iam_role.iam_role_for_lambda.arn}"
  filename = "../Archive.zip"
  source_code_hash  = "${base64sha256(file("../Archive.zip"))}"
  source_dir = "../"
  git_commit = ""
}

module "core-lambda-function2" {
  source  = "./lambda"
  name    = "core-lambda-function"
  runtime = "nodejs6.10"
  role    = "${aws_iam_role.iam_role_for_lambda.arn}"
  filename = "../Archive.zip"
  source_code_hash  = "${base64sha256(file("../Archive.zip"))}"
  source_dir = "../"
  git_commit = ""
}
```

this is what i currently have.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

while read p; do
  NAME=$p
  GIT_COMMIT=`git rev-parse HEAD`
  echo $NAME | grep `xargs` main.tf -A 7 | sed -ri '7s/git_commit = ""/git_commit\ = \"'$GIT_COMMIT'"/g'
done < build_name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not [Input Variables in Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/intro/getting-started/variables.html)?

```
variable "git_commit" {}

module "core-lambda-function1" {
  source  = "./lambda"
  name    = "core-lambda-function"
  runtime = "nodejs6.10"
  role    = "${aws_iam_role.iam_role_for_lambda.arn}"
  filename = "../Archive.zip"
  source_code_hash  = "${base64sha256(file("../Archive.zip"))}"
  source_dir = "../"
  git_commit = "${var.git_commit}"      #### Use variable here.
}
```

So in your wrapper script, you can update to:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

GIT_COMMIT=$(git rev-parse HEAD)

terraform plan -var 'git_commit=${GIT_COMMIT}' ...
```

Comment: Like this too:
    
    terraform plan -var "git_commit=`git rev-parse HEAD`"